# Media attachment pages giving 404's

Tags: media, 404-error

I use Google Webmaster Tools to track and fix 404's. I've been getting numerous 404's from media attachment pages, but not the page itself, it's parent.

An example:

I have this piece of media, http://www.casterconcepts.com/series-60-heavy-duty-caster-60-08202-60-2-rigid/60-08202-61-2/

If you go to its parent, it's a 404. In GWT (google webmaster tools), this 404 pops up and is said to have been linked FROM the media attachment page.

Does anybody know what's going on here and how to resolve this?

Comment: http://www.casterconcepts.com/series-60-heavy-duty-caster-60-08202-60-2-rigid/ is 404. Seems like a problem with your permalinking schema or your breadcrumbs plugin.

Comment: Hmmm yes. It seems as though WP gives the piece of media a permalink that is a direct descendant of the page you uploaded it from. So it's possible that the parent page was deleted, but this piece of media was not. Seems like WP should have a way of dealing with this. This makes Google's spiders throw 404's all over the place.

Comment: Kill the breadcrumbs on attachment page? Make users use their "back" button